# Error: socket hang up when using npm install with node.js v0.12.4

Tags: node.js, web, npm

I have a problem when installing express-mail.

```html
C:\mynode>npm install express-mail -g
-


> contextify@0.1.14 install C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expre
ss-mail\node_modules\juice2\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild
\

//After a few minutes

C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express-mail\node_modules\juice2\
node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (n
ode "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modul
es\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: socket hang up
gyp ERR! stack     at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:215:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:300:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:129:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at _stream_readable.js:908:16
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ivan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express-mail\node_mo
dules\juice2\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--msvs_version=2013" "install" "express-m
ail" "-g"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! contextify@0.1.14 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.14 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\mynode\npm-debug.log
```

I'm using node.js v0.12.4, Python 2.7, and Windows 7 64-bit. I have set environment variables PythonPath = C:\Python27 and PYTHON = C:\Python27\python.exe. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have node-gyp installed? Can you check and confirm. If you do not have node-gyp, install it.

Comment: I've just installed node-gyp. But I still got the same error.